# Chrome Extension : Redirecting with regexSubstitution but keeping path if existing

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Im trying to create a extension that automaticly changes the url from amazon.com to amazon.de while keeping the path if a path is given using chrome.declarativeNetRequest.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/

I tried multiple things and the following one is almost working.
The problem is the URL Changes to https://www.amazon.de%241/ and not to https://www.amazon.de/.
Same thing happens if I enter the link with a given path. It always redirect to https://www.amazon.de%241/

in the manifest.json file i added following line

manifest.json

```json
[...]
 "declarative_net_request": {
        "rule_resources": [{
            "id": "ruleset_1",
            "enabled": true,
            "path": "rule.json"
        }]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "declarativeNetRequest",
        "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"
    ],

[...]
```

rule.json

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "priority":1,
      "action":{
         "type":"redirect",
         "redirect":{
            "regexSubstitution":"https://www.amazon.de$1"
         }
      },
      "condition":{
         "regexFilter":"^https://www\\.amazon\\.com(/.*)?$",
         "resourceTypes":[
            "main_frame"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: `%24` is an URL-encoded `$` sign, so clearly this "back reference" did not get interpreted as such here. Where is the documentation for what you are trying to do there? So far, all you have shown us is basically _data_.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/ is the chrome API im trying to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it replace `$1` with `\1` as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#property-Redirect-regexSubstitution).

**A much more performant alternative** is to use [urlFilter](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#property-RuleCondition-urlFilter) + [transform](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-URLTransform):

```json
[{
  "id": 1,
  "condition": {
    "urlFilter": "|https://www.amazon.com/",
    "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
  },
  "action": {
    "type": "redirect",
    "redirect": {
      "transform": {
        "host": "www.amazon.de"
      }
    }
  }
}]
```